# Representation of base M digits in binary digits

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, information-theory, binary, binary-operations

In my textbook I came across the following sentence-

"If $M = 2^{m}$, with $m$ is a positive integer, then each base $M$
digit can be represented by a sub-sequence of $m$ binary digits"

Why is this true?

Let's say we are in base $M=16$. Then $M=2^{4}$ , i.e. $m=4$. 
What I'm guessing the above is saying is that if I have some base 16 digits, e.g. $1, 16, 256, 4096$ then all of these digits can be represented by 4 binary digits each? Personally, I can't see how this works. Clearly $256$ cannot be represented by 4 binary digits only.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 256 is not a base 16 digit.  the base 16 digits are $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F$ which in binary are $0,1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111$

Comment: In base $M$ there are $M$ digits from 0 to M-1.  These can be represented in binary as 0 to 111....1.  You are confusing "digits" with "powers" which are completely different and obviously false.  A power $M^k$ can be represented with one 1 and k-1 0 and in base 2 with mk > m zeros.  Indeed M will be the *first* number in binary that will need *more* than k binary digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers $1,16,256$ and $4096$ are not base $16$ digits, but rather they are powers of $16$, i.e. $16^0,16^1,16^2,16^3$. We need instead to consider digits.

Taking base $M=16=2^4$, then the digits are $0,1,2,\dots,E,F$, and these can be represented by equivalent binary strings $0000,0001,0010,\dots,1110,1111$, each of which contains $4$ binary digits.

So, given a base $16$ number, say $E2F_{16}$, we can immediately convert this to binary as $1110\,0010\,1111_2$.

As claimed, a similar conversion can be made in any base $M=2^m$ using $m$ binary digits for each base $M$ digit.

Comment: Worth noting is that *powers* of M will by definition require km + 1 binary digits to write.  M^1 will be the *first* number requiring more than m binary digits.